# Copying Javascript object attributes

Tags: javascript

I have 1 object coming from the server with multiple properties in which I want to hydrate it into a new object, changing the name of 1 property and keeping the rest.

Code:

JSON: `{ UserId: 1, Name: "Woo", Age: 10 }`

The format of the object I want it in:

```
var newObj = {}
newObj.id = jsonObj.UserId;
//Everything property below here is the same. How can i prevent writing this code?
newObj.Name = jsonObj.Name;
newObj.Age = jsonObj.Age;
```

What I'm doing is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600605/backbone-js-parse-1-element-the-id/6601316#6601316), trying to parse some json into a format that requires me to change the name of 1 property.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: Yes aroth is right.And to parse the json into a json object using jquery parseJSON method.

Comment: You have an excellent question friend, but it is hidden deep in line 3 of your comment box.  Also, I could be wrong but it seems you are not merging attributes, merely copying to a new Object.

Comment: stefgosselin, yea, I copying. I'll change the header

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For such a simple case, you could do something like:

```
var newObj = {id: jsonObj.UserId, Name: jsonObj.Name, Age: jsonObj.Age};
```

For a more complex object with a large number of fields, you might prefer something like:

```
//helper function to clone a given object instance
function copyObject(obj) {
    var newObj = {};
    for (var key in obj) {
        //copy all the fields
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }

    return newObj;
}


//now manually make any desired modifications
var newObj = copyObject(jsonObj);
newObj.id = newObj.UserId;
```

Comment: Hey, nice. Is this function "Deep copy",  does it work with inner objects that jsonObj has set as properties?

Comment: @stefgosselin - No, it is not a proper deep copy implementation.  That would require recursing through any `Array` and `Object` fields in the object.  If the object being copied contains any such fields, this method only creates a shallow copy of the nested objects/arrays.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to copy only specific fields

```
    /**
    * Returns a new object with only specified fields copied.
    * 
    * @param {Object} original object to copy fields from
    * @param {Array} list of fields names to copy in the new object
    * @return {Object} a new object with only specified fields copied
    */ 
    var copyObjectFields = function (originObject, fieldNamesArray)
    {
        var obj = {};

        if (fieldNamesArray === null)
            return obj;

        for (var i = 0; i < fieldNamesArray.length; i++) {
            obj[fieldNamesArray[i]] = originObject[fieldNamesArray[i]];
        }

        return obj;
    };


//example of method call
var newObj = copyObjectFields (originalObject, ['field1','field2']);
```

Answer (score 3):

I mostly prefer to reuse instead of recreate so I'd suggest http://underscorejs.org/#clone

Answer (score 1):

```
function clone(o) {
 if(!o || 'object' !== typeof o)  {
   return o;
 }
 var c = 'function' === typeof o.pop ? [] : {};
 var p, v;
 for(p in o) {
 if(o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
  v = o[p];
  if(v && 'object' === typeof v) {
    c[p] = clone(v);
  }
  else {
    c[p] = v;
  }
 }
}
 return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using Object.assign

```
var newObj = Object.assign({}, jsonObj);
```

[reference (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

## Using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify;

```
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont really understand your question, but this is what I normally do when I extract from an existing object:

```
var newObj = new Object(jsonObj);
alert(newObj.UserId === jsonObj.UserId); //returns true
```

Is that what you were asking? Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 Nice tip. Just to be sure, JS not my main language, `newObj` _would be a copy of jsonObj and not a reference where changing value in jsonObj won't affect newObj ? .. I should of slapped this in fiddle but too lazy. heh :)

Comment: It will be a copy, and you always access the read/write attribute using newObj.Id. If you change the attributes using .prototype, then it will change the values in the base class :)

Comment: I like this solution for its conciseness, but it comes with an important caveat:  `newObj` and `jsonObj` will refer to the same object.  So changing a field in one causes the same change to appear in the other.  Here's an example demonstrating this:  http://jsfiddle.net/3JvAd/

Comment: @aroth  Nice demo.  So what is the way to do a deep copy?  Is it `assign` ?

Comment: I have downvoted since the code is doing a shallow copy which is not what the OP were likely intending